# RESTeasy Database connection: NullPointer

Tags: mysql, jboss, nullpointerexception, resteasy

I have a RESTeasy service thats running on JBOSS AS 7, that is trying to create a connection with a local database (mysql server).

The data source is properly defined in the JBOSS management and connects fine (a JSF app can connect fine with it and it can modify the database), however when I try to connect in my RESTeasy service, it gives me a nullPointerException and I can't seem to figure out why. kumonobs is the database in question. The error occurs in the persist method, which is called through a post request. Any help would be much appreciated, if any additional information is needed please ask!

```
@Path("/RSAndroid")
@ApplicationScoped
public class HelloWorldResource implements Serializable{
@Resource(mappedName = "java:jboss/datasources/kumonobs")
private static DataSource dataSource;

private static ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();


@GET()
@Produces("text/plain")
public String sayHello() {
    return stringStudents(students);
}

@POST()
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
public String postStudent(@FormParam("Student ID") String student){
    Date date = new Date();
    Student kumonstudent = new Student(student, date);
    studentCheck(kumonstudent); 
    System.out.println(kumonstudent.toString());
    return "OK";
}


public String stringStudents(ArrayList<Student> s){
    String students = "";
    for(Student student : s){
        students += student.toString();
    }   
    return students;
}

public void studentCheck(Student student){
    boolean checkIn = true;
    int count = 0;

    for(Student s : students){
        count++;
        //If Student has been found in the list.
        if(s.getStudentID().equals(student.getStudentID())){
            //remove the student from the list.
            students.remove(count-1);
            // ** DO DATABASE STUFF HERE FOR REMOVING STUDENT **
            checkIn = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    //If student needs to be checked in, add to list.
    if(checkIn){
        System.out.println(student.getDate());
        students.add(student);
        // ** DO DATABASE STUFF HERE FOR ADDING STUDENT **
        persist(student);


    }
}
//Insert student into database table.
public void persist(Student student) {
     PreparedStatement stmt = null;
       Connection connection = null;
       try {
           try {
               connection = dataSource.getConnection(); //ERROR OCCURS HERE NULLPOINTER
            try {
                 System.out.println("Fourth");
                stmt = connection.prepareStatement(
                        "INSERT INTO checkin VALUES (?, ?)");
                stmt.setString(1, "A00105010");
                stmt.setString(2, "Sample Name");
                stmt.executeUpdate();
            } finally {
                if (stmt != null) {
                    stmt.close();
                }
            }
        } finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.close();
            }
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error in persist ");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Stack

```
14:29:22,040 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1) 2012-11-06
14:29:22,040 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].    [/AndroidRS].[Resteasy]] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1) Servlet.service() for servlet R
esteasy threw exception: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException:    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at         org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleApplicationException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:340) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
        at     org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:214)     [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleInvokerException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:190) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:540) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:502) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:119) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:208) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:50) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_27]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jboss.samples.rs.webservices.HelloWorldResource.persist(HelloWorldResource.java:92) [classes:]
    at org.jboss.samples.rs.webservices.HelloWorldResource.studentCheck(HelloWorldResource.java:81) [classes:]
    at org.jboss.samples.rs.webservices.HelloWorldResource.postStudent(HelloWorldResource.java:44) [classes:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_27]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) [rt.jar:1.6.0_27]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) [rt.jar:1.6.0_27]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) [rt.jar:1.6.0_27]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:155) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethod.java:257) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:222) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:211) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:525) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
    ... 19 more
```

Comment: Please add the stacktrace or the log file to have another pair of eyes look at your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, instead of the Annotation to the datasource use:

```
String strDSName = "java:jboss/datasources/thenamehere";
ctx = new InitialContext();
dataSource = (javax.sql.DataSource) ctx.lookup(strDSName);
```